# Book: a boy stranded on a planet who joins mercenaries, fights a space battle and disarms a nuclear bomb

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

Some time ago, I read some books about a boy who stops some evil dude using a supercomputer made of brains from planet populations or something like that. It later turns out that this evil dude was selling information to spacefaring civilisations and used these brains to solve alien questions.

The protagonist helps some aliens, and later, maybe in the second book, he is traveling with them when they are attacked, and he uses an evacuation pod, ending up on some planet where he joins some mercenaries. There, he helps in some space battle, affecting the outcome. After he rejoins the first set of aliens, he disarms a nuclear bomb in some court.

There is also mentioned somewhere that, sometimes, some civilisations experience sudden change, a technology leap, or "ascend".

Answer (score 2):

I've only skimmed parts of the series, but this sounds like the William Shatner/W.T. Quick series [*Quest for Tomorrow*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?5153), most likely the second book [*In Alien Hands*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1026299).

The "evil dude" would be Delta, the head of the "Combined Intelligence Agency" who, it turns out, was responsible for the creation of the "mind arrays" which would be the "supercomputer made of brains."  The mind array doesn't require *harvesting* the brains, it's much easier to convince people to accept implants in order to entertain themselves and use their brains that way.

> "All over the earth were useless humans.  Surplus of the techno age.  The Plebs, doing themselves and humanity no good as parasites.  Many of them addicts of the worst sort.  Wire headers content to—how do they say it?—plug in, turn off."
>
> He smiled bitterly.  "So it was self-selecting. I arranged it so that 90 percent of the wire head sockets implanted in those useless people were links to the arrays.  They picked themselves, Tabitha!  They chose to drop out of the human race, and by their choice, they gave me the way to save it, instead.  Imagine that..."
>
> <sub>[*Delta Search*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1026297)</sub>

Delta used the arrays notionally to the advantage of humanity, sometimes solving problems for humanity, but sometimes selling problem solving to aliens, since he felt that humanity needed something to make up for being fairly late-arriving and primitive relative to nearby alien races.  (He did this despite the fact that every time the mind arrays were used a fraction of the minds linked into them suffered psychotic breaks.)

The second book, *In Alien Hands* has the series' protagonist, Jim Endicott working with a (dog-like) people called Albans against another (alligator-like) people called Hunzza.
He joins a mercenary company, the *Red Death*, and makes a run to the Alban homeworld on a ship called the *Queen of Ruin*.  When the ship is attacked by a Hunzza battlegroup he meshes with the computer and leads the ship to destroy the entire Hunzza force.  They land on Alba, and at a ceremony for the crew a nuclear bomb is discovered, designed to kill the Packlord (head of government) and implicate Earth.  Since it is an Earth weapon, Jim is the only one who can disarm it.

The "Leap," a form of technological transcendence, comes up as a plot point in the third book [*Step Into Chaos*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1026300) as other races try to prevent it happening to humanity.

[image: Cover of "Delta Search"]
[image: Cover of "In Alien Hands"]
[image: Cover of "Step Into Chaos"]